# C++ struggling to make withdrawal and normalizing cents with dollars

Tags: c++

I have everything else setup properly and working, but I have fried my brain trying to get my withdrawal setup working. I just need help with the formula, it works fine except for when the total cents goes below 0

```
void SavingsAccount::deposit()
{
    int dollarHold, centHold, holder;
    cout << "Please input the dollars to be deposited: ";
    cin >> dollarHold;
    cout << "Please input the cents to be deposited: ";
    cin >> centHold;
    if (centHold > 99)
    {
        holder = centHold / 100;
        centHold -= (holder * 100);
        dollarHold += holder;
    }
    dollars += dollarHold;
    cents += centHold;
    if (cents > 99)
    {
        holder = cents / 100;
        cents -= (holder * 100);
        dollars += holder;
    }
    cout << "Dollar: " << dollars << " Cents: " << cents << endl;
}

void SavingsAccount::withdrawl()
{
    int dollarHold, centHold, holder;
    cout << "Please input the dollars to be withdrawn: ";
    cin >> dollarHold;
    dollarHold *= -1;
    cout << "Please input the cents to be withdrawn: ";
    cin >> centHold;
    centHold *= -1;

    if (centHold < 0)
    {
        holder = centHold / 100;
        centHold -= (holder * 100);
        dollarHold += holder;
    }

    dollars += dollarHold;
    cents += centHold;
    if (cents < 0)
    {
        holder = cents / 100;
        cents += (holder * -100);
        dollars -= holder;
    }

    cout << "Dollar: " << dollars << " Cents: " << cents << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying `dollarHold` and `centHold` by `-1`?

Comment: to turn them to negatives. Ive tried multiple ways, this is just the last attempt at it that i copied/pasted in here

Comment: You might find it easier to just store the money as cents and then just use math to display it as dollars and cents when you need to.  Then addition and subtraction become trivial.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot do that, im following instructions via my professor.

Comment: Try and convince him it is better this way.  If you make a valid argument he should allow it.  I don't know why so many programming teachers want you to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: I wish I could lol. We are currently learning classes and this just so happens to be the way we must follow it for both the input and output.

Comment: I can only have 2 member variables, dollars and cents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to store the balance in cents and display it in dollars and cents.

Then, the functions would be simplified to:

```
void SavingsAccount::deposit()
{
    int dollars, cents;
    cout << "Please input the dollars to be deposited: ";
    cin >> dollars;
    cout << "Please input the cents to be deposited: ";
    cin >> cents;

    int total = dollars*100 + cents;

    // Assuming balance is the new member variable and stored in cents.
    balance += total;

    dollars = balance/100;
    cents = balance%100;
    cout << "Dollar: " << dollars << " Cents: " << cents << endl;
}

void SavingsAccount::withdrawl()
{
    int dollars, cents;
    cout << "Please input the dollars to be withdrawn: ";
    cin >> dollars;
    cout << "Please input the cents to be withdrawn: ";
    cin >> cents;

    int total = dollars*100 + cents;

    // Assuming balance is the new member variable and stored in cents.
    balance -= total;

    dollars = balance/100;
    cents = balance%100;
    cout << "Dollar: " << dollars << " Cents: " << cents << endl;
}
```

However, if you must store the data in dollars and cents, you can simplify the member functions by converting everything to cents locally in the functions.

```
void SavingsAccount::deposit()
{
    int dollarHold, centHold, holder;
    cout << "Please input the dollars to be deposited: ";
    cin >> dollarHold;
    cout << "Please input the cents to be deposited: ";
    cin >> centHold;

    int total = (dollars + dollarHold)*100 + (cents + centHold);

    dollars = total / 100;
    cents = total % 100;

    cout << "Dollar: " << dollars << " Cents: " << cents << endl;
}

void SavingsAccount::withdrawl()
{
    int dollarHold, centHold, holder;
    cout << "Please input the dollars to be withdrawn: ";
    cin >> dollarHold;
    cout << "Please input the cents to be withdrawn: ";
    cin >> centHold;

    int total = (dollars - dollarHold)*100 + (cents - centHold);

    dollars = total / 100;
    cents = total % 100;

    cout << "Dollar: " << dollars << " Cents: " << cents << endl;
}
```